# PHP/SQL/Json Parse

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm super new to php, so I need some help. I'm having a hell of a time... and I know it's simple!

I have a php file here: 
http://theclackamasprint.net/json.php

It's pulling info from mysql to json.

I want a parse URL to separate the articles by their catid (not shown)

so I want to be able to type
http://theclackamasprint.net/json.php?catid=84
http://theclackamasprint.net/json.php?catid=87

etc... and have only those catid show

Here's my code:

```
$host = "******";
$db = "******";
$user = "******";
$pass = "******";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT title FROM tcp_content WHERE catid=84 ORDER BY publish_up DESC LIMIT 20";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a broken record, but since you're new to PHP you should really not learn/use the `mysql_*` database calls. They're being [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and may be removed from new PHP versions. `mysqli_*` and `PDO` (for example) are the modern ways to access MySQL from PHP.

Answer (score -1):

The shortest solution involves changing `catid=84` to `catid=" . $_GET['catid'] . "`, thereby plugging in the catid parameter into your MySQL query.

The resulting line will look like

```
$query = "SELECT title FROM tcp_content WHERE catid=" . $_GET['catid'] . " ORDER BY publish_up DESC LIMIT 20";
```

*HOWEVER* this is vulnerable to SQL injection, so if this is for any serious work, be sure to switch to either `mysqli_query()` or `PDO::query()`.

Comment: I don't find "this is how you do it, but it's totally insecure so don't do it" to be a very good answer. At the very least, please make use of [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: thanks! that worked... I'll make that change. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Considering this is a Q&A website, it is not an answer's responsibility to advocate best practices and such. A "very good answer" can range from using mysqli/PDO (like you recommended), to a dedicated ORM, to a standalone web framework that handles requests entirely. This answer is the *shortest* solution.